# system/core/include/utils/String16.h:20:10: fatal error: 'string' file not found

Tags: raspberry-pi, custom-rom

[image: console output]

I was trying to build PixelExperience 9.0 pie rom. I only get `string file missing`  error. I looked inside that string16.h file but I didn't understand much. Does anyone know why it's happening.

some helpful links:

https://github.com/PixelExperience/system_core/blame/255cbb3f80575fa90628fd3914cfe195d0c6f899/libutils/include/utils/String16.h#L20

rom source: https://github.com/PixelExperience

Comment: what exactly did you do here?

Comment: I was just trying to build rom and that error pops up after the build running for almost an hour. but previously i have made some modifications to my device , vendor , common , kernal source to get past the few errors i have encounterd before. complete error log, take a look from error line 3929 [  https://del.dog/yacojakiza.rb ] and my device treed  [ https://github.com/doraemon-mvl?tab=repositories ] u can see changes i've made to my tree here.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you work with **Android.mk**:

   ```
   LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=             \
           $(TOP)/system/core/include/utils \
   ```
2. If you work with **Android.bp**:

   ```
   include_dirs: [
       "system/core/include/utils",
   ],
   ```